# Arm navigation with a virtual robot

Tags: ros, planning-scene, arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have read the [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials/Understanding%20the%20Planning%20Scene%20architecture) on the new arm_navigation architecture, and I am really excited to try it out. As most tutorials have not been updated yet, do you have any code example that shows how to plan a movement using a robot position which is different from the current one?

Let's say the robot is at (x,y,th), and I want to see if I can reach a place by moving the robot to (x', y', th'). How can I do it using the planning scene?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11534/arm-navigation-with-a-virtual-robot/) by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1342 on 2011-10-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Lorenzo,

It should be pretty easy.  Basically, you are going to put a different transform between the world frame (in this case 'odom_combined') and the frame associated with the base of the robot ('base_footprint').  If operating with a running system you'll take the current state, apply whatever multi-dof and joint states are in the planning_scene_diff, and push the result to all components, who will then respond accordingly.  You'll want to interact with the components directly instead of using MoveArm, as you probably don't want to actually act based on state that's not the current one, though you are given the option.

Here's some code for generating IK solutions given another base configuration for your robot:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>

#include <kinematics_msgs/GetKinematicSolverInfo.h>
#include <kinematics_msgs/GetConstraintAwarePositionIK.h>
#include <arm_navigation_msgs/SetPlanningSceneDiff.h>

static const std::string ARM_COLLISION_IK_NAME = "/pr2_right_arm_kinematics/get_constraint_aware_ik";
static const std::string ARM_QUERY_NAME = "/pr2_right_arm_kinematics/get_ik_solver_info";
static const std::string SET_PLANNING_SCENE_DIFF_NAME = "/environment_server/set_planning_scene_diff";

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  ros::init (argc, argv, "get_fk");
  ros::NodeHandle rh;

  ros::service::waitForService(ARM_QUERY_NAME);
  ros::service::waitForService(ARM_COLLISION_IK_NAME);
  ros::service::waitForService(SET_PLANNING_SCENE_DIFF_NAME);

  ros::ServiceClient set_planning_scene_diff_client = rh.serviceClient<arm_navigation_msgs::SetPlanningSceneDiff>(SET_PLANNING_SCENE_DIFF_NAME);
  ros::ServiceClient query_client = rh.serviceClient<kinematics_msgs::GetKinematicSolverInfo>(ARM_QUERY_NAME);
  ros::ServiceClient ik_with_collision_client = rh.serviceClient<kinematics_msgs::GetConstraintAwarePositionIK>(ARM_COLLISION_IK_NAME);

  arm_navigation_msgs::SetPlanningSceneDiff::Request planning_scene_req;
  arm_navigation_msgs::SetPlanningSceneDiff::Response planning_scene_res;

  planning_scene_req.planning_scene_diff.robot_state.multi_dof_joint_state.stamp = ros::Time::now();
  planning_scene_req.planning_scene_diff.robot_state.multi_dof_joint_state.joint_names.push_back("world_joint");
  planning_scene_req.planning_scene_diff.robot_state.multi_dof_joint_state.frame_ids.push_back("odom_combined");
  planning_scene_req.planning_scene_diff.robot_state.multi_dof_joint_state.child_frame_ids.push_back("base_footprint");
  planning_scene_req.planning_scene_diff.robot_state.multi_dof_joint_state.poses.resize(1);
  planning_scene_req.planning_scene_diff.robot_state.multi_dof_joint_state.poses[0].position.x = 4.0;
  planning_scene_req.planning_scene_diff.robot_state.multi_dof_joint_state.poses[0].orientation.w = 1.0;

  if(!set_planning_scene_diff_client.call(planning_scene_req, planning_scene_res)) {
    ROS_WARN("Can't get planning scene");
    return -1;
  }

  // define the service messages
  kinematics_msgs::GetKinematicSolverInfo::Request request;
  kinematics_msgs::GetKinematicSolverInfo::Response response;

  if(query_client.call(request,response))
  {
    for(unsigned int i=0; i< response.kinematic_solver_info.joint_names.size(); i++)
    {
      ROS_DEBUG("Joint: %d %s",i,response.kinematic_solver_info.joint_names[i].c_str());
    }
  }
  else
  {
    ROS_ERROR("Could not call query service");
    ros::shutdown();
    exit(-1);
  }

  // define the service messages
  kinematics_msgs::GetConstraintAwarePositionIK::Request  gpik_req;
  kinematics_msgs::GetConstraintAwarePositionIK::Response gpik_res;

  gpik_req.timeout = ros::Duration(5.0);
  gpik_req.ik_request.ik_link_name = "r_wrist_roll_link";

  gpik_req.ik_request.pose_stamped.header.frame_id = "odom_combined";
  gpik_req.ik_request.pose_stamped.pose.position.x = 4.75;
  gpik_req.ik_request.pose_stamped.pose.position.y = -0.188;
  gpik_req.ik_request.pose_stamped.pose.position.z = .94;

  gpik_req.ik_request.pose_stamped.pose.orientation.x = 0.0;
  gpik_req.ik_request.pose_stamped.pose.orientation.y = 0.0;
  gpik_req.ik_request.pose_stamped.pose.orientation.z = 0.0;
  gpik_req.ik_request.pose_stamped.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;

  gpik_req.ik_request.ik_seed_state.joint_state.position.resize(response.kinematic_solver_info.joint_names.size());
  gpik_req.ik_request.ik_seed_state.joint_state.name = response.kinematic_solver_info.joint_names;

  for(unsigned int i=0; i< response.kinematic_solver_info.joint_names.size(); i++)
  {
    gpik_req.ik_request.ik_seed_state.joint_state.position[i] = (response.kinematic_solver_info.limits[i].min_position + response.kinematic_solver_info.limits[i].max_position)/2.0;
  }
  if(ik_with_collision_client.call(gpik_req, gpik_res))
  {
    if(gpik_res.error_code.val == gpik_res.error_code.SUCCESS)
    {
      for(unsigned int i=0; i < gpik_res.solution.joint_state.name.size(); i ++)
      {
        ROS_INFO("Joint: %s %f",gpik_res.solution.joint_state.name[i].c_str(),gpik_res.solution.joint_state.position[i]);
      } 
    }
    else
    {
      ROS_ERROR("Inverse kinematics failed");
    }
  }
  else
  {
    ROS_ERROR("Inverse kinematics service call failed");
  }
  ros::shutdown();
}
```

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2011-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3